# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I've been getting the SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) error for a while now.

People don't seem to be able to tell be what the cause of this error is.
This is probably my fault, by not explaining it well enough.
I hoped that any of you guys would want to help me by fixing this problem.
This would be really, really appreciated.

Warm regards,

Newbiedev

Comment: The problem is that the username/password combination for your mysql connection are invalid. ` Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is an MySQL connection error.

In this case the error states that you'r credentials aren't set correct. You should check your connection credentials and try again.

First check from e.g. PHPmyAdmin what the credentials are and then set them correctly in your connection file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

means your credential are invalid. Check the credentials again and try again with the right one.